# How to detect commutative patterns in Ocaml using pattern matching?

Tags: warnings, pattern-matching, ocaml

I need to detect a commutative pattern in one of my functions. I thought that writing the following will do the work:

```
let my_fun a b = match a,b with
  (*...*)
  | a,b
  | b,a when is_valid b -> process b  (***)
  (*...*)
```

This doesn't work and Ocaml complains with *this sub-pattern is unused*
warning for the line marked with `(***)`.

1) Can someone explain to me what this warning try to say and why this doesn't work?

<strike>2) How can I actually write this elegantly without using `if then else` given the fact that I want to now which argument `is_valid`?</strike>

2) Is it possible to get the intended functionality using only pattern matching and without repeating `when is_valid b -> process b` as it happens bellow?

```
let my_fun a b = match a,b with
  (*...*)
  | a,b when is_valid b -> process b
  | b,a when is_valid b -> process b 
  (*...*)
```

*Edit:*

In my concrete example `a` and `b` are pairs. The function is a bit more complicated but the following will illustrate the case:

```
let f a b = match a,b with
  | (a1,a2),(b1,b2)
  | (b1,b2),(a1,a2) when b1 = b2 -> a1 + a2
```

Calling `f (1,1) (1,2)` will yield pattern match failed. I know understand why (thanks to the answers bellow) and I understand how I can make it work if I have different constructors for each element (as in Ashish Agarwal's answer). Can you suggest a way to make it work in my case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matching works by first matching the pattern, and if that succeedes, then by evaluating the condition with the attached environment from that pattern match. Since `a,b` will always bind, this is the only case used, and the compiler is correctly reporting that `b,a` is never used. You'll have to repeat that line,

```
let my_fun a b = match a,b with
  | a,b when is_valid b -> process b
  | b,a when is_valid b -> process b
```

Your method could work if you didn't perform the match with variables but to some variant, for example,

```
let my_fun a b = match a,b with
  | a, `Int b
  | `Int b, a when is_valid b -> process b
```

*Edit:* Think of the multiple patterns using one guard as a subexpression,

```
let my_fun a b = match a,b with
  | ((a,b) | (b,a)) when is_valid b -> process b
```

You'll see this exemplified in the definition for [patterns](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html). It's really one pattern, composed of patterns, being matched.

Comment: By the way, not to be "RTFM", but here is the source for this information if you're interested, http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html

Comment: Based on the documentation you also pointed out after a match is found the condition is evaluated. If the condition is false then the matching is resumed. This means that in my example after matching a,b it should test is_valid b. So a,b should not bind always. Can you help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: I know that the repeating the line will work, but that's why I'm trying to avoid (what follows after is not just one line). 

The variant solution also doesn't work for me. I basically get the same stuff but without the warning.

Comment: I mentioned the variants to show you can use guards on multiple matches, not as a viable 'solution'. It would be difficult to suggest something when we only know two lines of code. But if it's longer then one line, you can always create a function just above the match, and call it making it one line.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is clear now why things work as they do. As for a concrete example I don't know if it will add more value. Based on my current understanding and your answer it is not possible to get rid of the code duplication in this case. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway, I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Aside from the obvious (to make another function), and without knowing more information on those types your matching, it's hard to offer much advice. It seems like you're confident you cannot unify those matchings, so it looks like duplication is unavoidable.

Comment: Although not exactly what I was looking for you answer helped me the most. Since it is a low probability to get another one I'll accept it:)

Answer (score 4):

For your first question, the thing to realize is you only have one pattern `((a,b) | (b,a))`, which happens to be an "or" pattern. Matching proceeds from left to right in an "or" pattern. Since `(a,b)` will match anything, the second part will never be used.

For your second question, I don't see the problem, but it depends on the types of `a` and `b`. Here's an example:

```
type t = A of int | B of float

let my_fun a b = match a,b with
  | A a, B b
  | B b, A a when b > 0. ->  (float_of_int a) +. b
  | … -> (* other cases *)
```

It would also work for simpler types:

```
let my_fun a b = match a,b with
  | 1,b
  | b,1 when b > 0 -> b + 1
  | … -> (* other cases *)
```

If you still can't get this to work in your case, let us know the types of `a` and `b` you are working with.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see how I can make it work if I have different constructors. Still, I can't make it work in my case. I updated the question with a concrete example.